# Classifying subintervals of natural numbers

Tags: categorical-data, data-mining

Suppose we are given a positive integer $N$. I am interested in relations between subintervals of the intervals of natural numbers $[1,N]$.

For each $k\leqslant N$ let $\mathscr{I}_k$ denote the family of subintervals of $[1,N]$ of length $k$.

We are given (deterministic) subfamilies (possibly empty) $\mathscr{L}_k\subseteq \mathscr{I}_k$ ($k\leqslant N$). For two intervals $I,J\subset [1,N]$ we define a quasi-distance 
$$d(I,J)=\text{ number of elements in the smallest interval containing both }I\text{ and }J.$$

Fix $2\leqslant j\leqslant N$, indices $k_1, \ldots k_j\leqslant N$ and numbers $\ell_{km}\leqslant N$ such that $\ell_{lm}=\ell_{mk}$ ($k,m\leqslant j$).

> I would like to decide whether the occurrence of $j$-tuples $(I_1, \ldots, I_j)$ with $I_k\in \mathscr{I}_k$ and $d(I_k, I_m)=\ell_{km}$ is statistically more significant than other configurations of such $j$-tuples.

I am no expert in data analysis but I believe there must have been developed tools to decide such problems. I would appreciate any indication for statistical tests/algorithms that would be of use here.

Comment: What is your applied problem? How does your data arise?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without more information: it is missing any sense of a random process.  Two good ways to present that information are to answer @kjetilbhalvorsen's question or to give an explicit mathematical description of a probability model for the $j$-tuples in question.